Api Gateway Ingress Controller is not redirecting correctly
I have two microservices in azure, both work correctly and communicate correctly, but it turns out that when I use the ip of the gateway with the routes of the ingress, only the default path works, if I place there the microservice store, the store will appear in web page, if I place the microservice admin, that microservice will appear but not the other when I do for example http://<ip-gateway>/store or vice versa.
Here you have the ingress code
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
name: my-ingress
namespace: ecommerce
annotations:
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/connection-draining: "true"
appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/connection-draining-timeout: "60"
spec:
rules:

- http:
  paths:
  - path: /
    pathType: Prefix
    backend:
    service:
    name: ecommerce-store
    port:
    number: 3001
  - path: /admin
    pathType: Prefix
    backend:
    service:
    name: ecommerce-admin
    port:
    number: 3000

And the code of the services
Store microservice:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ecommerce-store
  namespace: ecommerce
spec:
  selector:
    app: ecommerce-store
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 3001
      targetPort: 3001
  type: ClusterIP

Admin microservice:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ecommerce-admin
  namespace: ecommerce
spec:
  selector:
    app: ecommerce-admin
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
  type: ClusterIP

Another thing, when I use the ip and add /admin , I see for a few seconds the microservice admin interface but immediately the apigateway or ingress redirect me to the microservice of the default path which in this case is the microservice store.
I tried changing the order, the default path for the admin and the store, but when I do this, the same thing happens.

Avoid Root Path. Use /store and /admin as distinct paths. This will ensure that traffic to /store goes to the ecommerce-store service and traffic to /admin goes to the ecommerce-admin service.

URL Rewrite for Azure Application Gateway for Containers - Ingress API


Please try the below setup for your AGIC to route to the specified paths.
Create the deployment for the store microservice:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ecommerce-store
  namespace: ecommerce
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ecommerce-store
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ecommerce-store
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: store
        image: yourstoreimage:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3001

create a service for the same
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ecommerce-store
  namespace: ecommerce
spec:
  selector:
    app: ecommerce-store
  ports:
    - port: 3001
      targetPort: 3001
  type: ClusterIP

apply them
kubectl apply -f ecom-deployment.yaml
kubectl apply -f ecom-service.yaml


Do the same for admin microservice
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ecommerce-admin
  namespace: ecommerce
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ecommerce-admin
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ecommerce-admin
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: admin
        image: youradminimage:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000

admin service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ecommerce-admin
  namespace: ecommerce
spec:
  selector:
    app: ecommerce-admin
  ports:
    - port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
  type: ClusterIP

apply them
kubectl apply -f admin-deployment.yaml
kubectl apply -f admin-service.yaml

define ingress class and ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  namespace: ecommerce
  annotations:
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/connection-draining: "true"
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/connection-draining-timeout: "60"
spec:
  ingressClassName: appgw
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /store
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: ecommerce-store
            port:
              number: 3001
      - path: /admin
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: ecommerce-admin
            port:
              number: 3000



Ensure you have an application gateway and AGIC configured beforehand. Follow the setup mentioned in MS Doc and once done verify the same

you should be able to set up the Application Gateway and the AGIC to correctly route traffic to your microservices.
